# xxx cannot be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm attempting to get 2 different values from 2 different variables from an array and multiply them, then add them together; but, as I try to use the code later, an error pops up.

my code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
class HW {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] uno = {3, 5};
      ArrayList<Integer> obj1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int a = (uno[0]);
      int b = (uno[1]);
    }
    public static void man(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> obj2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int [] dos = {7, 6};
      int a1 = (dos[0]);
      int b1 = (dos[1]);
    }    
    public static void an(String[] args) {
      int x = ((uno[0]) * b1);
      int y = (a1 * b);
      System.out.println(x + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the following variables have a scope that is method scope, which means they can only be accessed within the method they are declared:

- `uno`: only available in `main` method
- `b1`: only available in `man` method
- `a1`: only available in `man` method
- `b`: only available in `main` method

Why not putting all the code in a single method?

```java
class HW {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] uno = {3, 5};
      int a = (uno[0]);
      int b = (uno[1]);

      int [] dos = {7, 6};
      int a1 = (dos[0]);
      int b1 = (dos[1]);

      int x = ((uno[0]) * b1);
      int y = (a1 * b);
      System.out.println(x + y);
  }
}
```

Comment: @tortyturty, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.